# AspectJ causing "Editor does not contain a main type" error

Tags: eclipse, ide, workflow, aspectj, ajdt

After installing the AspectJ Development Tools into Eclipse, the "Run" button and the Ctrl-F11 shortcut both become nearly useless: using them (or the Debug button) will throw an "Editor does not contain a main type" error message, even for *projects that do not require a main type to be present* (eg. Android application projects). Standalone Java projects with a proper main type defined work fine - so it seems AJDT is forcing Eclipse to check for a Java main() without checking the project type first. Whether or not the project is an AspectJ project makes no difference, either.

The problem only appears when the file you are currently editing has either ".java", ".aj" or ".class" anywhere within its filename (note: it doesn't actually have to end with those extensions, as long as it's anywhere in there - readme.txt will work, readme.java.txt won't).

Two ways I've found to work around this - regardless of whether or not it's an AJ project - after installing AJDT is:

- Select a file within your project in the Package Explorer whose name doesn't contain .java, .class or .aj, and *then* hit Run (the Package Explorer has to remain active and selected).
- Create a new Run Configuration for your project, and use it to launch your project. This still adds a pointless extra step, as well as being impractical for those who work with a lot of projects.

I've tried this on both Eclipse Juno and Helios (Windows XP x86 as well as Win7 x64), the result is the same. While it might seem like nitpicking it certainly isn't: AJDT is hijacking *the* most frequently used function of the IDE.

I've resorted to having two different Eclipse installations with their own separate workspaces on my work PC, one with AJDT installed, and one without, so I can use the IDE properly when I'm not working on anything AJ-related. Since my company is working on a project that would require other developers to install AJDT into their IDEs, this is a significant issue for us that goes beyond our own loss of time - I can't imagine a lot of developers would be willing to put up with a significant bottleneck being added to their workflow for absolutely no reason at all. So most likely, they will just ditch our product instead!

---

**Update:** This has been identified to be a bug inside AspectJ, and has been reported to the AJ development team. You can keep track of it here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=399660
As of this writing, the bug has already been *partially* fixed, restoring Run functionality to non-AJ-enabled projects.

Comment: Never heard of this problem...are you saying hat even in java projects, the key binding is broken? Worth raising an audit bug for this on http://bugs.eclipse.org

Comment: The key binding isn't broken, the function itself is. (Ctrl-F11 and the Run button both result in the error message.) And yes, this happens in all projects, even simple Java ones that have nothing to do with AJ. :(

This has been happening to me on two rather different systems (my work PC running Windows XP 32bit and the newer Eclipse Juno, and my home PC running Windows 7 64bit and the older Eclipse Helios), the only common point being AJDT (I've never seen this message outside of this issue).

Comment: Now, I am getting confused as to what your problem is.  Please clearly state exactly what is working and what is not working in your question.  Is this only happening for AJ projects or Java projects too?  Is it only the keybinding that's broken, or all ways of launching your apps?  Are there any errors in the error log?

Comment: Thank you for asking me to clarify, it made me do some experimentation that has shed some light on the potential source of the issue! :-) I've updated the original question accordingly.
With a Java-only project, the error disappears as soon as I define a proper main(), as it should. The problem I was having was because the type of project (Android) I was working on does not require a main() to be present at all. So the cause of the issue seems to be that AJDT is forcing Eclipse to check for main() irrespective of project type.

No errors in the log, key shortcut and Run button work the same.

Answer (score 1):

I was just coming on this site to ask the same question. While I don't have an answer for why this is going wrong, I have a workaround which is helping me currently:

Go to **Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching** and select **Always launch the previously launched application**. This will introduce bearable behaviour when working on a single project. You will need to manually create a run configuration for your main class.

Comment: I used to do this, but it doesn't help when you need to work on multiple projects. :(

I reported the bug to the AJDT development team, and they are working on resolving the issue! (See link in original post)